# How to specify a function operating on non-empty data structure with LiquidHaskell?

Tags: haskell, smt, liquid-haskell

I am trying to do the first exercise in the LiquidHaskell [case study on Lazy Queues](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-tutorial/09-case-study-lazy-queues.html)

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello"

{-@ type Nat   = {v:Int | 0 <= v}        @-}

{-@ die :: {v:String | false} -> a @-}
die x = error x

{-@ measure realSize @-}
realSize      :: [a] -> Int
realSize []     = 0
realSize (_:xs) = 1 + realSize xs

{-@ data SList a = SL {
       size  :: Nat 
     , elems :: {v:[a] | realSize v = size}
     }
  @-}
data SList a = SL { size :: Int, elems :: [a]}

{-@ type NEList a = {v:SList a | 0 < size v} @-}

{-@ hd           :: NEList a -> a @-}
hd (SL _ (x:_))  = x 
hd _             = die "empty SList"

okList = SL 1 ["cat"]
okHd   = hd okList
```

`okHd` fails:

```
 app/Main.hs:30:13-18: Error: Liquid Type Mismatch
   Inferred type
     VV : {VV : (SList [Char]) | VV == Main.okList}

   not a subtype of Required type
     VV : {VV : (SList [Char]) | 0 < size VV}

   In Context
     VV : {VV : (SList [Char]) | VV == Main.okList}
     Main.okList
        : (SList [Char])
```

From the error message, I'm pretty sure I'm not giving enough information to LH for it to "know" that `okList` is non-empty, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I tried telling it explicitly with a post-condition(?):

```
{-@ okList :: NEList a @-}
okList = SL 1 ["cat"]
```

But this doesn't work:

```
 app/Main.hs:29:5: Error: Specified Type Does Not Refine Haskell Type for Main.okList
 Haskell: Main.SList [GHC.Types.Char]
 Liquid : forall a. Main.SList a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your refined type of `okList` is not restricting the type. It restricted the size but loose the type from `String` to `a`.

Change

```
{-@ okList :: NEList a @-}
okList = SL 1 ["cat"]
```

to

```
{-@ okList :: NEList String @-}
okList = SL 1 ["cat"]
```

And it will work.

---

I have to admit that I don't know liquidhaskell very well so everything below may only be my wild guess:

The main reason you have to do this is you are defining `okList` separately with the default constructor `SL`. The refined type of `SList` only promises that `size v = realSize (elems v)`, the size of the list is inspected when you call the constructor, compared with the number literal and then discarded, not stored at (liquid) type level. So when you feed `okList` to `hd`, the only information available for reasoning are `size v = realSize (elems v)` (from the refined data type) and `size v >= 0` (`size` is defined as a `Nat`), `hd` won't know if it's positive.

In `hd okList`, liquidhaskell may not be able to evaluate the expression and by doing so substitute `okList` with `Sl 1 ["cat"]` and gain information about the size, so it can only make judgement depend on the refined type of `okList` it inferred (in this case, `SList String`). One evidence is `hd $ SL 1 ["cat"]` will work with no refined type.

Comment: This did indeed work, but it's not clear to me why this matters - I'm not making any assertions based on the concrete String type. Is this a limitation of the tool, or is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: @XavierShay updated. I hope my explanation is satisfactory.

Comment: thank you! The final example helped ("One evidence...").